# Display employee position based on years of service

Tags: sql, database, group-by, case, union

I want to display a list of employees who are still active (not resigned at this time) based on the length of their tenure, their tenure based on years, namely: 0-5 years, 6-10 years, 11-20 years, 21-30 years, > 30 years. for each term of office, the position is also stated. because there may be more than 1 listed position for 1 term of office, then the positions are made with commas
appear : years of service, amount, position.

I've tried this code, but it's not working as I want.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,A.JoinDt,SYSDATE()) AS 'Years Of Service', COUNT(A.EmpCode) AS 'Amount', B.PosName
FROM tblemployee A
INNER JOIN tblposition B ON A.PosCode = B.PosCode
WHERE A.ResignDt IS NULL
GROUP BY B.PosName
```

This is what I expecting for

| Years Of Service | Amount | Position Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-5 | 10 | Manager |
| 6-10 | 10 | Manager |
| 11-20 | 10 | Manager |
| 21-30 | 10 | Manager |
| >30 | 10 | Manager |

Can someone help me, please ? Thanks

Ps : the amount and the position name above, just a example for the output. And sorry I can't provide the input script due the term and condition with my client

Comment: please tag your RDBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**SQL QUERY SHOULD WORK LIKE THIS:

LISTAGG Function may needs to be replaced as it don't support every database but we need to look for alternative function.** 



SELECT A.'Years Of Service',A.PosName,LISTAGG(PosName, '; ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PosName) as "Aggregated_Pos_name",
A.Amount

FROM   (SELECT CASE WHEN (SYSDATE()- a.joindt)/365 <= 5 THEN '0-5'
WHEN (SYSDATE()- a.joindt)/365 BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '6-10'
END AS 'Years Of Service', COUNT(A.EmpCode) AS 'Amount', B.PosName
FROM tblemployee A
INNER JOIN tblposition B ON A.PosCode = B.PosCode
WHERE A.ResignDt IS NULL)A
GROUP BY A.Years of Service;
```